# Elasticsearch path.repo prevents service being started

Tags: elasticsearch, debian

I want to store my snapshots here:

```
/root/backups/elastic
```

So I've added this line at the end of /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:

```
path.repo: ["/root/backups/elastic"]
```

When I try to start elasticsearch service, an error says that service failed to stard.
After commenting that line I can start the service again.
In the log file an error says that:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.repo' (/root/backups/elastic)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:316)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:262)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:118)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setupSecurity(Bootstrap.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:183)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:45)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /root/backups
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:308)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:702)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:337)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addPath(Security.java:314)
```

I used these commands to solve the problem:

```
sudo chmod 777 /root/backups/
sudo chown elasticsearch /root/backups/
sudo chown elasticsearch /root/backups/elastic/
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's cos of the line you added? Any other *error* trace?

Comment: @Darth_Vader Yes! after commenting that line I can start the service again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all using the root directory is a very bad idea for backups and given all permissions it is a security nightmare. The `AccessDeniedException`is likely that the `root` directory is not accessible for elasticsearch.

```
$ ls -l /root
ls: cannot open directory '/root': Permission denied
$ ls -l /
drwx------  10 root root       4096 Jan 25 22:41 root
```

If you really want to test just `chmod o+rx /root` and the exception should go away. I strongly recommend to use a shared SAN/NAS mountpoint or AWS S3 file storage for backups.

Second I assume you using the Shared filesystem approach.

You may need to add some information to deduce the problem. How many nodes you have in your cluster? What elasticsearch version you are running?

The setting `path.repo` must be in `elasticsearch.yml` of **all** nodes in the cluster. Even if the nodes start, backups may fail and thus the restore.

Comment: What are alternate ways to give permission to the ES image? I would rather not `0+rw`' my dirs for security purposes.